# Enter to raw_input automatically

Tags: python

Just as an example, it might seem illogical. I have a get_name function as below, and wanted to write a automated script to call this function and enter to the `raw_input` automatically.

```
def get_name ():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your name : ")
    print "Hi " + name
```

The automated script as below, what command should I add to enter my value automatically?

```
def run ():
    get_name ()
    // what should I add here?
```

Comment: If it is your own script, just decouple the information input (the raw_input call) from the processing. If it is a third party shitty API which does not offer "batch mode", do what Anand S Kumar is suggesting, but bear in mind it is a little bit cumbersome...

Answer (score 6):

You can redirect your `stdin` to a file , and then `raw_input()` would read from that file.

Example -

```
def run():
    import sys
    f1 = sys.stdin
    f = open('input.txt','r')
    sys.stdin = f
    get_name()
    f.close()
    sys.stdin = f1
```

Please note, after you do - `f = open('input.txt','r')` and `sys.stdin = f` , raw_input() would read from the `<filename>` file.

Once you are done with the get_name() call, close the file and restore the stdin using `sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__` , if you want to restore it back to console input, otherise you can restore it to `f1` , which would restore it to the state it was before test started.

Please note, you should be careful when redirecting inputs like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can also substitute `stdin` with [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (aka memory file) instead of real file. This way the entered text will be in your testing code instead of separate text file.

based on Anand S Kumar's (+1):

```
def run():
    import sys
    import StringIO
    f1 = sys.stdin
    f = StringIO.StringIO('entered text') # <-- HERE
    sys.stdin = f
    get_name()
    f.close()
    sys.stdin = f1
```

Also, for more sophisticated testing of interactive commandline functions/tools you may want to check the [pyexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) package.

Comment: Nice! but it does not work on jupyter notebook, any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to make the input function a parameter, *defaulting* to `raw_input`:

```
def get_name(infunc=raw_input):
    name = infunc("Please enter your name : ")
    print "Hi " + name
```

Then for testing purposes you can pass in a function that does whatever you need:

```
get_name(lambda prompt: "John Smith")
```

Answer (score 3):

For testing you could call your script from the command line with IO redirection - see subprocess in the manuals but for a quick solution you could change your code like this, *note that this does not test raw_input but lets you simply test the surrounding code*:

```
def get_name (name=''):
    """ Code to get the name for testing supply name int the call """
    if len(name) == 0:
        name = raw_input("Please enter your name : ")
    print "Hi " + name

def run ():
    get_name ("Fred")
```

Comment: This is an acceptable answer. However I would split the `say_hello` function, from the `ask_user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 users

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

def getInput():
    value = input()
    print(value)

sys.stdin = StringIO('test')
getInput()
```

Output:

```
test
```